# How to test Google App Invites

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services, install-referrer

I'm currently implementing [Google's App Invites](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/) 
and I'm wondering what the best way to test fresh installs.

I can broadcast an `INSTALL_REFERRER` event with the appropriate deep link like so:

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n <your.package>/.<path.up.until.your.BroadcastReceiver> --es "referrer" "test_referrer=test"`

But this would send a generic broadcast out with referral data. Is there currently a way to broadcast a `INSTALL_REFERRAL` which also contains the appropriate `AppInviteReferral` data?

Digging into the source reveals that there is a `com.google.android.gms.appinvite.REFERRAL_BUNDLE` included as a part of the intent, but I'm unsure how to construct that as a part of the broadcast.

**edit**
I have created a separate, more general question regarding the use of bundle extras when testing broadcasts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655231/how-to-include-a-bundle-extra-when-testing-android-broadcasts)

Comment: what did you do in the end?

Comment: @sivi I ended up not going forward with the app invites, but a valid approach to test this was presented in another answer.. Basically, create a test app to send the broadcast event with the appropriate referral bundle. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31411910/2263561

Answer (score -2):

I would use the demo app found [here](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/start) as a starting point. You can just grab the code there and test with other devices that have your app installed. NOTE: your app has to already have been published to the play store

Comment: This information would be better as a comment on the question. An answer would include the solution directly.

Comment: @user3071284 I could not comment as I don't have enough reputation to do so